# Custom problem matcher for problems in files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I would like to match problem output from a program with JSON output.

I have a file `output.json`. The format is roughly like this:

```
  "warnings": [
    {
      "file_location": "abc.hpp",
      "line": 73,
      "msg": "Some warning message"
    }
```

I would like to show these in the problems view.

1. How do I read problems from file (do I need to use `cat/type`?). All the examples seem to be for npm watch or similar.
2. Even with `output.json` my current tasks don't show this.

I've defined the following task:

```
    {
        "label": "show problems",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "cat output.json",
        "problemMatcher": {
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}"],
            "pattern": [
                {
                    "regexp": "^\\s*\"file_location\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.+)\",$",
                    "file": 1
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^\\s*\"line\"\\s*:\\s*(\\d+),$",
                    "line": 1
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^\\s*\"msg\"\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)$",
                    "message": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your problem matcher, but problem matchers always tend to be a bit awkward, especially for "reading problems from a file" like here. Have you considered writing an extension using the diagnostics API? That seems like a much cleaner, easier and more flexible approach.

Comment: @Gama11 No, but I'll check it out, I hadn't heard of it before. I have an internal extension for snippets already, so I could maybe easily extend that. Thank you :)

Comment: @Gama11 I now made an extension and it works beautifully and works much better for distribution anyway. If you add a proper response I can accept your answer there. (You can't accept comments as answers).

Comment: Hm.. glad it helped, but I don't think "do something else instead" really answers the original question. Somebody else who finds the question might still be wondering how this can be done using problem matchers. :)